# Convert specified column in a multi-line string into single comma-separated line

Tags: string, bash, shell, csv

Let's say I have the following string:

```
something1:    +12.0   (some unnecessary trailing data (this must go))
something2:    +15.5   (some more unnecessary trailing data)
something4:    +9.0   (some other unnecessary data)
something1:    +13.5  (blah blah blah)
```

How do I turn that into simply

```
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

in bash?

Comment: Let's step back for a moment and consider this thread a glaring indictment of bash as a programming language.  Consider Scala's `listOfStuff mkString ", "`, or Haskell's `intercalate ", " listOfString`

Comment: Related: [Convert text file into a comma delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53093449/6862601)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use `awk` and `sed`:

```
awk -vORS=, '{ print $2 }' file.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Or if you want to use a pipe:

```
echo "data" | awk -vORS=, '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

To break it down:

- `awk` is great at handling data broken down into fields
- `-vORS=,` sets the "output record separator" to `,`, which is what you wanted
- `{ print $2 }` tells `awk` to print the second field for every record (line)
- `file.txt` is your filename
- `sed` just gets rid of the trailing `,` and turns it into a newline (if you want no newline, you can do `s/,$//`)

Comment: awk: invalid -v option :(

Comment: Add a space between -v and ORS=, (for me, on osx)

Comment: How to do the same command for getting pipe separated? `awk -v ORS=| '{ print $1 }' DCMC.rtf | sed 's/,$/\n/'` am getting an error

Comment: strangely, when I try to do this, the output is empty.

Comment: I think for piped version it should be `{print $1}` otherwise I'm getting only commas in output

Answer (score 230):

Clean and simple:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt | paste -s -d, -
```

Comment: This is the best answer here, and obviously the correct way to do this

Comment: How do I quote every values with single/double quote?

Comment: @Hussain `cat thing |  awk -F',' '{ print "'\''" $7 "'\' '" }' | paste -s -d ','`

Comment: How use `,'` as the delimiter?

Comment: Remember to handle *Windows newlines* (eg using `dos2unix`) if there are any CRLFs in the string.

Comment: wish I knew about `paste -s -d',' -` sooner ... I've been using `blah=$(...|tr '\n' ',');echo "${blah:0:-1}"` or perl one-liners for ages... this is so much cleaner

Comment: A more concise version: `awk '{print$2}' file.txt | paste -sd,`

Answer (score 28):

```
cat data.txt | xargs | sed -e 's/ /, /g'
```

Comment: I like solutions like this too but is the -e arg necessary here since there's only the first command being used for sed? I believe `cat data.txt | xargs | sed 's/ /, /g'` would work all the same. For example, `echo -e "foo\nbar\nbazz" | xargs | sed 's/ /, /g'` outputs **foo, bar, bazz**.

Answer (score 18):

This might work for you:

```
cut -d' ' -f5 file | paste -d',' -s
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

or

```
sed '/^.*\(+[^ ]*\).*/{s//\1/;H};${x;s/\n/,/g;s/.//p};d' file
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

or

```
sed 's/\S\+\s\+//;s/\s.*//;H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/\n/,/g' file
```

For each line in the file; chop off the first field and spaces following, chop off the remainder of the line following the second field and append to the hold space. Delete all lines except the last where we swap to the hold space and after deleting the introduced newline at the start, convert all newlines to `,`'s.

N.B. Could be written:

```
sed 's/\S\+\s\+//;s/\s.*//;1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/\n/,/g' file
```

Comment: Most elegant is the usage of `paste`! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

**awk** one liner

```
$ awk '{printf (NR>1?",":"") $2}' file

+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

Comment: Format specifier `"%s",` should be added after `printf` to make it more robust i.e. to make it work with all kind of rows such as "foo %s".

Answer (score 11):

```
$ awk -v ORS=, '{print $2}' data.txt | sed 's/,$//'
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

---

```
$ cat data.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

Comment: cheers, what about if the input to awk was through standard input (just put `function | awk...` in your example?

Answer (score 8):

This should work too

```
awk '{print $2}' file | sed ':a;{N;s/\n/,/};ba'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -o "+\S\+" in.txt | tr '\n' ','
```

which finds the string starting with `+`, followed by any string `\S\+`, then convert new line characters into commas. This should be pretty quick for large files.

Answer (score 5):

Try this easy code:

```
awk '{printf("%s,",$2)}' File1
```

Comment: It adds an extra comma

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
sedSelectNumbers='s".* \(+[0-9]*[.][0-9]*\) .*"\1,"'
sedClearLastComma='s"\(.*\),$"\1"'
cat file.txt |sed "$sedSelectNumbers" |tr -d "\n" |sed "$sedClearLastComma"
```

the good thing is the easy part of deleting newline "\n" characters!

EDIT: another great way to join lines into a single line with sed is this: `|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` got from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/tlacgw).

Answer (score 2):

A solution written in pure Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

sometext="something1:    +12.0   (some unnecessary trailing data (this must go))
something2:    +15.5   (some more unnecessary trailing data)
something4:    +9.0   (some other unnecessary data)
something1:    +13.5  (blah blah blah)"

a=()
while read -r a1 a2 a3; do
    # we can add some code here to check valid values or modify them
    a+=("${a2}")
done <<< "${sometext}"
# between parenthesis to modify IFS for the current statement only
(IFS=',' ; printf '%s: %s\n' "Result" "${a[*]}")
```

Result: +12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5

Comment: Alternatively you could use `read -r -a cols` and thereafter add `"${cols[1]}` to the list `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't seen this simple solution with awk

```
awk 'b{b=b","}{b=b$2}END{print b}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
fg@erwin ~ $ perl -ne 'push @l, (split(/\s+/))[1]; END { print join(",", @l) . "\n" }' <<EOF
something1:    +12.0   (some unnecessary trailing data (this must go))
something2:    +15.5   (some more unnecessary trailing data)
something4:    +9.0   (some other unnecessary data)
something1:    +13.5  (blah blah blah)
EOF

+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with two sed calls:

```
$ cat file.txt 
something1:    +12.0   (some unnecessary trailing data (this must go))
something2:    +15.5   (some more unnecessary trailing data)
something4:    +9.0   (some other unnecessary data)
something1:    +13.5  (blah blah blah)
$ sed 's/^[^:]*: *\([+0-9.]\+\) .*/\1/' file.txt | sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/,/; ta'
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

First sed call removes uninteresting data, and the second join all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also print like this:

Just awk: using **printf**

```
bash-3.2$ cat sample.log
something1:    +12.0   (some unnecessary trailing data (this must go))
something2:    +15.5   (some more unnecessary trailing data)
something4:    +9.0   (some other unnecessary data)
something1:    +13.5  (blah blah blah)

bash-3.2$ awk ' { if($2 != "") { if(NR==1) { printf $2 } else { printf "," $2 } } }' sample.log
+12.0,+15.5,+9.0,+13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl solution, similar to Dan Fego's awk:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[1],"' file.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

`-a` tells perl to split the input line into the @F array, which is indexed starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well the hardest part probably is selecting the second "column" since I wouldn't know of an easy way to treat multiple spaces as one. For the rest it's easy. Use bash substitutions.

```
# cat bla.txt
something1:    +12.0   (some unnecessary trailing data (this must go))
something2:    +15.5   (some more unnecessary trailing data)
something4:    +9.0   (some other unnecessary data)
something1:    +13.5  (blah blah blah)

# cat bla.sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat bla.txt); do
  i=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}')
  u="${u:+$u, }$i"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
echo "$u"

# bash ./bla.sh
+12.0, +15.5, +9.0, +13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another AWK solution

Run

```
awk '{printf "%s", $c; while(getline){printf "%s%s", sep, $c}}' c=2 sep=','
```

to use the 2nd column to form the list separated by commas. Give the input as usual in standard input or as a file name argument.