# How do I extract the second element from rows in a list, and store the elements in a comma separated line in a new file using BASH?

Tags: bash

I have rows and columns preceded by an introduction that I do not need. There are no headers for the columns. The data in my current file looks something like this (IP Addresses are fake):

```
This is a totally extraneous introduction and does not have anything to do with the data. It is here as a facsimile of what the output file looks like.

df    bank.com 10.10.10.1
sdfdg store.com 10.10.10.2
s     church.com 10.10.10.3
```

I need to skip past the introduction, paste in the extracted data to look like this below (derived from field two above), and put it all into a new `.txt` file. The strings do not need quotes:

```
bank.com,store.com,church.com
```

Any advice on how to do this in Bash?

I tried using this following technique, but it only grabbed the first line of the introduction, and did not go through each row.

[Turning multi-line string into single comma-separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714355/turning-multi-line-string-into-single-comma-separated)

Comment: You want to skip the first two lines?

Comment: I need to skip the introduction and grab data starting with the first row. I only need the second element from each row, saving those elements in a new file where they are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- always skip the first 2 lines of the input file
- the second field contains no white space
- there are no blank lines

Sample data file:

```
$ cat input.dat
This is a totally extraneous introduction and does not have anything to do with the data. It is here as a facsimile of what the output file looks like.

df    bank.com 10.10.10.1
sdfdg store.com 10.10.10.2
s     church.com 10.10.10.
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'FNR>2 {printf "%s%s", pfx, $2; pfx=","} END {printf "\n"}' input.dat
bank.com,store.com,church.com
```

Explanation:

- `FNR>2` - for record (row) numbers greater than 2 ...
- `printf "%s%s", pfx, $2` - print our prefix (initially blank) plus field #2; because there is no `\n` in the format the cursor is left on the current line
- `pfx=","` - set prefix to a comma (`,`) for the rest of the file
- `END {printf "\n"}` - add a `\n` to the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
tail -n +3 filename | awk '{print $2}' | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' > newfile.txt
```

The `tail -n +3` will skip the first 2 lines of the file (so change this to  however many lines the intro is, plus one).

The next part prints out only the second column, the one you're interested in.

The third replaces the newlines with commas.

The last part places the output into a new file.

Comment: Thank you!  It worked for me after install gnu-sed for MacOS!